# What other OCaml top level programs exist? (Vista)

Tags: windows, ocaml, ocaml-toplevel

I'm using OCamlWinPlus v1.9RC4. It sucks pretty hardcore. It's constantly crashing, and lacks basic features. What other toplevel OCaml programs can be recommended for Windows Vista?

Comment: Did you mean toplevels for windows?

Comment: yeah sorry for not making that clear

Comment: @Rosarch: yeah it was pretty crappy when I used it in college, so I added to it...annnd I stopped fixing it when I stopped doing OCaml work. If I recall, it doesn't do Vista right if you're not an administrator. *(Obviously this is old, so you may not even use OCaml any more)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Windows version of Emacs and use the customization files (*.el) provided with OCaml's source archive to turn Emacs in a powerful, if idiosyncratic, toplevel.

You'll find the instructions in ocaml-3.11.1/emacs/README. Specifically:

> Once you have started caml by M-x run-caml:
>
> M-C-x   send phrase to inferior caml process
>   C-c C-r send region to inferior caml process
>   C-c C-s show inferior caml process
>   C-c`    goto error in expression sent by M-C-x

Answer (score 1):

I used ocaml from cmd. Editing with history is there..

Can you elaborate on ocamlwinplus crashes? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: it seems to crash randomly. It will crash when I paste something in, or when I hit "submit". Then, I'll do the exact same thing, and it'll be fine.

Comment: launch it under windbg and save the dump whet it crashes, then put it on the web somewhere - these are the real steps that can help to locate the issue (I see an old bug for ocamlwinplus on mantis and no one managed to track it down..)

Answer (score 1):

I use Notepad++ to write code then I compile it from cmd, simply there is no simple way to do it with OCAML!